Create a QR code which sends to html email
Is it possible to initiate an html email from a scanned QR code?
I can create a QR code in vb.net using 'QRCoder' library which sets up an email when scanned, but this is plain text and I need to add a hyperlink. Is it possible to create an html format email using a similar method?
Sample code I'm using:
Dim email_subject As String = "This is the subject"
Dim email_body As String = "This is body"

Dim QR_text As String = $"mailto:{email_recipients_text}?subject={Uri.EscapeDataString(email_subject)}&body={Uri.EscapeDataString(email_body)}"

Dim QR As Bitmap = Containers.GenerateQRCode(QR_text)

Thanks!
